Chrome Remote Desktop: Kicked Out at Session Start
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on a home computer that I would like to access remotely via Google Chrome Remote Desktop. The workstation is usually running without a display or peripherals. I can access it via SSH.
In Remote Desktop, I have followed the "Set up via SSH" steps to install the client on the Ubuntu workstation. The computer does appear in the list. When I open it, I get the "Select a session to launch within your Chrome Remote Desktop environment" dialog. After making any selection, I'm immediately disconnected and the computer appears offline briefly:

Other pertinent details:

I am able to connect successfully with the "Remote Support" feature in Chrome Remote Desktop (but this isn't a long term solution since it requires me to access to the remote computer).
This is an issue when connecting from any device -- I've tried 2 MacBooks and 1 Android and have had the exact same issue.
When running chrome-remote-desktop commands, I get a Python warning:

$ /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start
/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop:2526: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  re.split('\s+', os.environ[HOST_EXTRA_PARAMS_ENV_VAR].strip())
2024-08-02 14:05:16,537:INFO:Service already running.


The Python version on the remote workstation is version 3.12.3.
I have tried following this answer but the solution is out of date, and not all of the suggested edits apply to the current version.


What is the picture that changes every 2 seconds supposed to be? It is very distracting and does not help.

@DavidDE It's a gif showing the errant behavior. If others upvote your comment I'll remove it.

sudo systemctl restart chrome-remote-desktop
